# SQL Server Dependencies missing

Tags: t-sql, dependencies

This may be a case of my ignorance to what is meant by a dependency.

When I run the following query I get a slightly different list (more entries) to when I chose the menu option View Dependencies (first node level only) why would that be? I should add I am ignoring VIEW dependencies, for example I have a 2 foreign key relationships set up to 2 different tables (pretty much identical configuration) yet only 1 is shown in the View Dependencies yet both a seen in the following query.

I got this off some other post:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pt.object_id PrimaryTableID, pt.name PrimaryTableName
FROM 
    REPDEV.sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN 
    REPDEV.sys.tables ft ON fk.referenced_object_id = ft.object_id
JOIN 
    REPDEV.sys.tables pt ON fk.parent_object_id = pt.object_id
WHERE 
    ft.name = 'MyTable'
ORDER BY 
    2
```

Am I suppose to use other means to get table relationship dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Include full outer join instead of join (inner join) and add the clause

"fk.name is not null" in where.

Tell me if works :)

Comment: Don't understand how this helps. The point is say TableX has a foreignkey replationship (FK=MyTableID) to MyTable (PK=ID)  then when I right click MyTable and choose View Dependencies and leave the default (Objects that depend on [MyTable]) I should see TableX in the dialog if I don't click on anything else. The foreignkey field allows nulls and I guarantee all non null values have a match to MyTable's single field PrimaryKey. As far as I am concerned my query that I have posted is showing the correct result, i.e. TableX shows up when i run the query.